# Django error "The secret_key setting must not be empty" after upgrading from 1.4.3 to 1.5.1

Tags: python, django, django-1.5, secret-key

I just upgraded my Django from 1.4.3 to 1.5.1 using `pip install django --upgrade`. After the upgrade, my dev site started getting Internal Server Error. I tried to run `./manage.py` command but it told me "The secret_key setting must not be empty". I checked my `settings.py` file and it does have a `SECRET_KEY` value there. So I don't know what's going on there. Someone else has the same problem?

Comment: There are many possible reasons. I found several googling for `"The secret_key setting must not be empty"`, so start there. If none of those help, you'll need to include the contents of your `settings.py` in the question.

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19428